# ADF - status succeeded but stop

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a simple flow to send a message whether there is error or not. In this scenario, I try to produce an error from `sp_Drop_Constraints`
[image]

And this is the error message:

```
Execution fail against sql server. Sql error number: 3728. Error Message: 'FK_ID__Group_Umum_' is not a constraint.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.
```

But this flow just works till `sp_Drop_err` and then stop. This Stored Procedure just like this [image]

I've tried to change the option (skip, complete and finish) but never continue to the next store procedure (`sp_End`) and the end send email notification.

So, why this happen and how to solve it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After splitting output, it can work till end.
Combine input, it will be as an  `AND` statement.

[image]